# Javascript more function onclick and ClassName

Tags: javascript, onclick, getelementsbyclassname

I need to make this function working. It should change display on div fullhouse and other two div with class change to margin from top to 0.
That function works only with displaying none.

Thank you in advance

```
 function fullhouse()
 {
 document.getElementById("fullhouse").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementsByClassName("header-container").style.margin-top = "0px";
 document.getElementsByClassName("top-icon-menu").style.margin-top = "0px";
 }
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` does not return a single element, but an HTMLCollection – you have to loop through the items in there and set the style for each item. And `.style.margin-top` is wrong as well – that would be a mathematical operation, `.style.margin` minus `top` – it needs to be `.style.marginTop`.

Answer (score 0):

Use **marginTop**, its not margin-top;

Here's the code:

```
function fullhouse()
{
   document.getElementById("fullhouse").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementsByClassName("header-container").style.marginTop = "0px";
   document.getElementsByClassName("top-icon-menu").style.marginTop = "0px";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it still doesn't work. I mean displayng to none works but the rest don't.

Comment: How your are calling this function?

Comment: Basic <a onclick="fullhouse()"> Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript any CSS properties that contain a dash are turned into a camel case variable name:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("header-container").style.marginTop = "0px";
document.getElementsByClassName("top-icon-menu").style.marginTop = "0px";
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong css property, correct one is **marginTop**

```
 document.getElementsByClassName("top-icon-menu").style.marginTop = "0px";
```